# Angular route is not working with Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, routes

I'm facing an issue with Cordova, Cordova-ios 6.2.0 and Angular 12.0.
When I'm building my app with Cordova and launch it in an emulator (or with a device), I'm arriving to a white screen.

I did some research and try some "fix" but nothing worked.
Finlly, I've find that it could be because of the  balise.
So, I tried to play with the tag  and modify the href with ., ./, / but nothing worked.
I've tried without and it worked, but without routing.

Has someone already had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular router needs the app to be hosted on a "proper" HTTP scheme and does not work with `file:` URLs. You can check how your app runs, if you open the JavaScript console for your app running on an iOS device with Chrome and typing `location.href`. If you see `file:` you need to set up a custom scheme.

Please checkout the documentation and this announcement https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

Comment: Hi Niklas!

Your solution worked as expected!

Thanks a lot!